# Use of PHP function to make multiple MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table named  "orders". I want to make functions so I can easily access how many orders was added during Last: Hours, Day, Week, Month and Year.

If I don't require file `dbconfig.php` in each function than I get ERROR :(

So far the code below works exactly as I want but I think its possible to shorten it?

```
<?php

function count_db_last_hour(){
require("../dbconfig.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE checkdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY checkdate DESC";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$connect->close();
return $result->num_rows;
}

function count_db_last_week(){
require("../dbconfig.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE checkdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY checkdate DESC";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$connect->close();
return $result->num_rows;
}

function count_db_last_day(){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE checkdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY checkdate DESC";
require("../dbconfig.php");
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$connect->close();
return $result->num_rows;
}

function count_db_last_month(){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE checkdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY checkdate DESC";
require("../dbconfig.php");
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$connect->close();
return $result->num_rows;
}

function count_db_last_year(){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE checkdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) ORDER BY checkdate DESC";
require("../dbconfig.php");
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$connect->close();
return $result->num_rows;
}

echo count_db_last_hour() . '<br>' . count_db_last_day() . '<br>' . count_db_last_month() . '<br>' . count_db_last_year() ;

?>
```

Is it possible to shorten this code? Thank you for helping out.

### **UPDATED:**

If I don't require `dbconfig.php` inside function I get ERROR:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: connect in /home/test2.php on line 9
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on
>   null in /home/test2.php:9 Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/test2.php(35): count_db_last_hour()
>   #1 {main} thrown in /home/test2.php on line 9

---

The `dbconfig.php` file has this code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "ordzxq_usar";
$password = "9ir3Grd_fXz";
$dbname = "store_orders";
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Try using `include`, then put it in the global scope

Comment: Can you post your error ?

Comment: Read about the [scope of variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one function and pass `type` to it:

```
function count_db_last_item($type) {
    $allowedTypes = ['HOUR', 'DAY',];   // and more
    // if type not allowed - return from function
    if (!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)) {
        return false;
    }

    require("../dbconfig.php");
    // add $type to query text
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE checkdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 $type) ORDER BY checkdate DESC";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    $connect->close();
    return $result->num_rows;
}
```

> If I don't require file dbconfig.php in each function than I get ERROR :(

You get error because `$connect` variable is not seen in your function. Just pass it as argument:

```
require("../dbconfig.php");

function count_db_last_item($type, $connect) {
    $allowedTypes = ['HOUR', 'DAY',];   // and more
    // if type not allowed - return from function
    if (!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)) {
        return false;
    }

    // add $type to query text
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE checkdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 $type) ORDER BY checkdate DESC";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    // if you really need to close connection - close it
    $connect->close();
    return $result->num_rows;
}
```

Comment: that's almost what i was about to answer. i would have answered using `require_once` outside of the function and `global $connect;` in the function, but it really depends on what is in dbconfig.php

Comment: Also if the connect is made global, then closing it isn't probably the most friendly thing to do in case any other code wants to use it.

Comment: @cyborg if you use the first version, you have to call it with this format: `echo count_db_last_item('HOUR') . '<br>' . count_db_last_item('DAY') . [... the rest]`. With the second solution, you must add $connect as second parameter to each function call too

Comment: Thanks a Million! Its really A NICE code! Much shorter than what I had :D

Comment: @Kaddath Thank you, it works perfectly now, I used the 1. code. The $type selection is really awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Create a one common function and just pass the $sql as the parameter dnt include dbconfig in each function instead of that pass the $connect as second parameter to the function

```
 function count($sql,$connect){       //$connect is your $conn variable
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    $connect->close();
    return $result->num_rows;
    }
 $sql= "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE checkdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY checkdate DESC";

$count_db_last_week =count($sql);

echo $count_db_las_week;
```